# Can anyone expound this Projectile Motion computation please?

Tags: kinematics, computational-physics, notation, projectile, software

I have this formula for projectile motion that I'm using in Unity game engine for getting the low or high Velocity of a projectile depending on how close or distant the target is (as long as it is within optimal range), and it works. However, I'd love to fully understand the equation.

I wrote the snippet of code below in C# language and I'm using `Vector3` to represent the velocity in `x, y, z` which gives me the direction and movement of a rigidbody (physics-influenced object).

So..

1. Why was `force` raised to the power of 4?
2. How to understand what's happening in `P`?
3. For the `low` and `high` vectors, how did it manage to get the right angles?
4. Ultimately, what formula/equation in Projectile Motion was this derived from?

```
Vector3 dir = target - origin;

float v2 = force * force;
float v4 = v2 * v2;
float g = -Physics.gravity.y;
float x = dir.x;
float y = dir.y;
float P = v4 - g * (g * x * x + 2f * y * v2);

float sq = Mathf.Sqrt(P);

low = new Vector3(g * x, v2 - sq);
high = new Vector3(g * x, v2 + sq);
```

Not sure if the below image is a correct equivalent of the formula (for the `y` of the vector), but I hope someone can recognize.

$$u^2\pm\sqrt{[u^4-g(gx^2+2yu^2)]}$$

Apologies as I'm not well-versed with many math equations especially physics, even though I'm a programmer.

I hope you understand my plight and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: What is meant by target? Is the projectile supposed to hit the target where the projectile lands? Is it supposed to hit it when the projectile reaches the highest point in its trajectory? Or something else? Also, where do you see the force raised to the power of $4$? I only see it being multiplied with itself once -- so that would be the power of $2$.

Comment: @DvijD.C. The assumption is the target is where the projectile would hit or land. If the target point is within optimal range, I will have two options: the projectile can either be launched at a high angle or low angle (up to me to choose) in which both case would hit the target. Regarding the power of 4, it's because of the variable 'float v4' where it's v2 * v2. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas thanks for that- I'll be sure to check it out.

Comment: If the Vector3 is a object of 3 memebers, why in the last assignment of low and high only give two numbers? What are the meanings of these two numbers?

Comment: @ytlu Vector3 can be used as Vector2 as well and the code above is still good syntax. For simplicity, assume where only using x, and y. In my actual code I replaced x with z. The two (or 3 in full 3d space) members  will dictate the direction of the vector.

Comment: Can you show the constructor of Vector3(float, float)?

Comment: @ytlu In Unity Engine's Vector3, yes, we can do that. The z will automatically be zero.

Comment: Is `force` a value or a vector? What does it represent, because it is not used like a force in the code snippet.

Comment: The `force` variable represents velocity (u). In Unity's rigidbody, it's just another term for speed or magnitude - if multiplied to the vector it becomes the velocity of the rigidbody. The rigidbody movement with direction and speed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a projectile trajectory $\left( x(t), y(t) \right)$ to pass through two points $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$, what is the launching velocity $v_0$ and angle $\theta$?

Write down two equations of the trajectory:
\begin{align}
x = & v_0 \cos\theta\, t; \tag{1}\\
y = & v_0 \sin\theta\, t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2. \tag{2}
\end{align}

rewrite these two equations:
\begin{align}
x = & v_0 \cos\theta\, t; \tag{3}\\
y + \frac{1}{2} g t^2 = & v_0 \sin\theta \,t. \tag{4}
\end{align}

Divide Eq.(4) with Eq.(3)
$$
 \tan\theta = \frac{y + \frac{1}{2} g t^2}{x}; \,\, \text{ or }\,\,\, x\tan\theta = y +\frac{1}{2} g t^2. \tag{5}
$$

Replace the variable $t$ in Eq.(5) by Eq.(3) $t = \frac{x}{v_0 \cos\theta}=\frac{x}{v_0}\sec\theta$

$$
  x\tan\theta = y + \frac{g x^2}{2 v_0^2} \sec^2\theta = y + \frac{g x^2}{2 v_0^2} \left(1+ \tan^2\theta\right).
$$

We have a quadratic equation for $\tan\theta$
$$
   \tan^2\theta -\frac{2 v_0^2}{g x} \tan\theta +\frac{2 v_0^2 y}{g x^2} +1 = 0.
$$

The solution for $\tan\theta$:
$$
\tan\theta = \frac{v_0^2}{g x} \pm \sqrt{ \left(\frac{v_0^2}{g x} \right)^2 -\left( 1 + \frac{2 v_0^2 y}{g x^2} \right)}
$$
$$
\tan\theta_\pm = \left( \frac{1}{g x} \right) \left\{v_0^2 \pm \sqrt{ v_0^4 -g \left( g x^2 + 2 v_0^2 y \right) } \right\}
$$

The term inside the curry braket resembles your equation. Therefore, your Vectors objects *low* and *high* record the denominator and numerator of $\tan\theta_\mp$.

After determined the angle $\tan\theta$, we again subtitute $t=\frac{x}{v_0\cos\theta}$ into Eq.(5) to calculate the speed $v_0$:

$$
  x\tan\theta = y +\frac{1}{2} g \frac{x^2}{v_0^2\cos^2\theta}.
$$

The launching speed $v_0$ expresses in term of launch angle $\tan\theta_\pm$:
$$
 v_{0\pm} = \sqrt{\frac{g x^2\left(1 + \tan^2\theta_\pm\right)}{ 2 \left(x\tan\theta_\pm - y\right)}}.
$$

Comment: This is awesome! It does resemble the equation. I will try this out with my data and do some reverse checking so I can fully grasp the equation. Thank you so much. I hope you could answer some questions in the future if there's any. Marking this as the current answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1865775 I found my error in the very beginning $y = v_0\sin\theta - \frac{1}{2} g t^2$. I mistyped $+\frac{1}{2} g t^2$. And I added in the answer the expression for the launch velocity in term of $\tan\theta$ for completeness.